# Why are there 2 bars when looking at a weapon's stats?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

When you choose a weapon when customizing a class, why are there 2 bars (a white bar and blue bar) for each weapon statistic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

White is your currently equipped weapon, blue is the weapon you're looking at.